# incorrect Guild ID

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, discord.py

**error reason**

> discord_slash.error. IncorrectGuildIDType:
> The snowflake IDs 520499240150106148 given are not a list of integers. Because of discord.py convention, please use integer IDs instead. Furthermore, the command 'nowplaying' will be deactivated and broken until fixed.

**the code**

```py
@slash.slash(
    name="nowplaying",
    description="Command to check what song is currently playing",
    guild_ids=(os.getenv("GUILD_IDS")),
)
async def nowplaying(ctx):
    try:
        if not Vc.is_playing():
            await ctx.reply("I need to play something first")
    except:
        await ctx.reply("I need to play something first")
    else:
        song_info = get_info.info(Tune)
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0xC0F207)
        embed.set_author(name="Now Playing ", icon_url=ctx.guild.icon_url).add_field(
            name="Playing", value=f"{song_info[1]} - {song_info[0]}", inline=False
        ).set_footer(
            text="This bot is still in development, if you have any queries, please contact the owner",
            icon_url=(ctx.author.avatar_url),
        )
        if song_info[2] is not None:
            embed.add_field(name="Album", value=f"{song_info[2]}", inline=True)
            if albumart is not None:
                try:
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=albumart[song_info[2]])
                except KeyError:
                    logging.warning("No Albumart found")
                    pass
        else:
            pass

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I'm very confused about this...

Comment: judging from the error, it seems that it wants that certain guild ID as an integer in a list even if it is just one ID. Maybe something like `[ID]` would work instead of `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slash command library you're using requires you to pass guild ids as integers. However, `os.getenv()` returns strings. You can convert a string to an integer using the `int()` function.

Another issue is that you're trying to pass a tuple, but because you only have one value, python thinks you're just trying to parenthesize the `os.getenv()` call. The solution is to add a comma right before the closing parenthesis.

This is what your code would look like:

```py
@slash.slash(
    name="nowplaying",
    description="Command to check what song is currently playing",
    guild_ids=(int(os.getenv("GUILD_IDS")),),
)
async def nowplaying(ctx):
    # Your code here
```